# Ratio of flagged employees to total employees for each department

Tags: sql

I have the following table. I'm trying to find the ratio of # of employees flagged as one to the total amount of employees on a department by department basis. Any idea? I've tried joining the two tables together only to have double the numbers of employees flagged as one

Here's the columns I have:

```
flag    department  employees
-----------------------------
 0      892684      10
 0      893432      29
 0      893561      4
 0      896114      2
 0      897783      18
 1      897783      77
 0      897853      7
```

I'm trying to get the result:

```
department  ratio
-----------------
897783       .81
892684       0
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Standard SQL, should run as-is in all DBMSes:

```
select
   department,
   sum(case when flag = 1 then employees else 0 end) -- flagged employees only
     / cast(sum(employees) as float)      -- all employees
       as ratio
from tab
group by department;
```